# SQL treats similar to English and Swedish characters

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

**Statement 1**

```
INSERT INTO `abc`.`a` (`name`) VALUES ('Otp1');
```

**Statement 2**

```
 INSERT INTO `abc`.`a` (`name`) VALUES ('Ötp1');
```

I have unique constraint on column `name`.

Statement 2 throwing following exception.

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'otp1' for key 'name' 0.000 sec
```

I tried to configure database with following settings,

1. Collation = utf8 - Defalut collation
2. Collation = utf8_swedish_ci

But, SQL is not able to differentiate between `o` and `Ö` due to that it is throwing exception.

Can anyone assist me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried `VALUES(N'Ötp1')`?

Comment: @lad2025 yes I tried this option but it is giving same error

Comment: I can't replicate this in 5.6... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1611/1 (I used utf8mb4 - but it actually makes no difference in this instance)

Comment: Did you look at what is shown by `SHOW VARIABLES '%connection'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved issue by changing following database properties to `utf8_swedish_ci` from `utf8_general_ci`

1. collation_connection,
2. collation_database,
3. collation_server properties